# Al correr sudo apt-get install -y node.js se supone debe de instalar el node.js y el npm sin embargo solo instala el node

Tags: nodejs, reactjs, ubuntu, windows, npm

[image: Terminal de linux en windows ubuntu]

Al revisar si tengo instalado npm me aparecen éste problema. Qué debo de hacer?
Soy novato.

Comment: Estas utilizando windows o alguna distro de linux?

Comment: Windows pero con el subsistema de linux, gracias :)

Answer (score 0):

Encontré la solución, fue entrar a Ubuntu como administrador y ejecutar los comandos sin el "sudo"del inicio. No sé si será la mejor vía pero funcionó para mi.